# How to use ng-click directive in column header of "ui-grid" in angularJs

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid directive to display results, 
In column header i am using headerCellTemplate to apply ng-click directive, I am calling simple sort_sq() , which should invoke a alert box.

But the alert box is not invoking.

it means ng-click is not working.

could Anyone suggest how make it work.

Comment: And? Does it invoke an alert box? And do you want that? And what is sort_sq()? Please be more specific.

Comment: hey i have updated the question hope now it will be clearly understandable.

Comment: Interestingly I see the same issue, but only on the iPad. Anyone know why?

Comment: I found the solution, need to use little jquery code in it. or else use latest version of ui-grid.js